# How to processing data with Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, angular, database, spring-boot

My project is to processing data from my database. I got an input text for entering xml data(plain text format), this part works but now I need to process this data to **extract the words I need** and push them into a **Graph** (vis.js). I'm using spring-boot 2.1.4 and angular 8. Thanks in advance for investigating ! love

I'have not trying anything, I only searched in the web. But I need you for **guide me**. If you have source or anything. It could be nice !

I tried this in google : "data processing spring boot angular"
and this : creating-rest-api-using-spring-boot

[My database](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6ea3)

## In springboot:

My Graph.java:

```
@Entity(name = "graphiques")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Graph {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name ="id")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name ="xml")
  private String xml;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "GraphQuery{" +
      "id" + id +
      ", xml ='" + xml + '\'' +
      '}';
  }
}
```

My GraphRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface GraphRepository extends CrudRepository<Graph, Long> {

}
```

My GraphController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public class GraphController {
  private GraphRepository graphRepository;
  @Autowired
    GraphController(GraphRepository graphRepository){
    this.graphRepository = graphRepository;
  }
  @PostMapping
  public Graph post(@RequestBody Graph graph){
    return this.graphRepository.save(graph);
  }
  //Ajout du xml dans la base
  @GetMapping("/{graph_id}")
  public Optional<Graph> get(@PathVariable Long graph_id) {
    return this.graphRepository.findById(graph_id);
  }
```

## In angular:

My graph.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('siteConfigNetwork', { static: true }) networkContainer: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initGraph();
  }

  initGraph() {
    let nodes = [
      { id: 1, label: 'Node 1' },
      { id: 2, label: 'Node 2' },
      { id: 3, label: 'Node 3' },
      { id: 4, label: 'Node 4' },
      { id: 5, label: 'Node 5' }
    ];

    let edges = [
      { from: 1, to: 3 },
      { from: 1, to: 2 },
      { from: 2, to: 4 },
      { from: 2, to: 5 }
    ];
    let container = this.networkContainer.nativeElement;
    let data = {
      nodes: nodes,
      edges: edges
    }
    let options = {};
    let network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
  }
```

I want my data be linked when multiple tag("to" and "from") are in one tag("note"). So the tag note will be the node and edges must start from this node and be linked to the node "to" and "from".
I don't know if I'm clear. Be indulgent I'm a little french who begin's in dev.
Thank's again for helping me !

Comment: Wait you are really using XML in a JSON message..

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as you need example data and expected results.. We cant reproduce easy from a image..

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes I'don't know how to say to angular its an xml format ( I tried to change `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to `'Content-Type': 'application/text'` but it don't work. Thanks for quick reply !